# know if the contours are neighbours in opencv android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

i am working on a rubiks cube scanner the app uses react native and opencv on android side

i have been able to detect all the square tiles but i want to verify all tiles are scanned for which i was thinking of checking if there are 9 square tiles neighbouring each other and then getting the average color for each tiles
[Scanned Rubiks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiM89.jpg)

```
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Object callback(@NonNull Frame frame, @Nullable Map<String, Object> arguments) {
    try {
      Image image = frame.getImage();
      byte[] bits = toJpegImage(image,100);
      String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(bits, Base64.DEFAULT);

      // decoding the base64
      byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
      Mat originalMap = new Mat(decodedByte.getWidth(),decodedByte.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
      Utils.bitmapToMat(decodedByte, originalMap);

      //preprocess the image
      Mat processedMat = processImage(originalMap);

      //border Mask from img
      Mat borderMask = borderMask(processedMat,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());

      //floodfill algorithum
      Mat floodFill = floodfill(borderMask,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());

      //Detect Square Grid
      List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
      List<MatOfPoint> squares = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

      Imgproc.findContours(floodFill,contours,new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

      for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
         //Detecting Square and pushing it to List square 
      }



      // encoding back to base64 string
      Utils.matToBitmap(originalMap, decodedByte);
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
      byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
      String grayscale = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

      return grayscale;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.v("Exception"," Error :- "+e.toString());
      return "Error :-"+e.toString();
    }
  }
```

i tried getting center of each contour and comparing it with other contours but I cant get it to work